# Java FXML load (Dynamic) from absolute path

Tags: java, fxml

I want to load fxml files from an absolute path or a path outside of my jar system.

background:
it will be a simple plugin-system that look's in the plugin folder for all fxml files (later jar files) and include it automatically in a TabPane.

```
String fxmlpath = "C:\\plugin\\pluginfxml.fxml";
try {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlpath));
    //Load root in Tabpane and so on ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is For fxml / class files ... not for jar Files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be simple:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Paths.get(fxmlpath).toUri().toURL());
```

FXMLLoader takes in a URL as its argument, so we just use the NIO *Paths* class to get the Path, then convert it to a URL. The only problem occurs if the program does not have read access to the file's location.'

I've fleshed out the example with the example code from the JavaFX tutorial:

Test application:

```
package javafx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FXMLTest.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        URL fxmlURL = Paths.get("C:\\test\\fxml_example.fxml").toUri().toURL();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(fxmlURL);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        Scene myScene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Example Controller:

```
package javafx;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLExampleController {
    @FXML private Text actiontarget;

    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }
}
```

Example FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>


<GridPane fx:controller="javafx.FXMLExampleController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
    styleClass="root">
    <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="25" left="25"/></padding>

    <Text id="welcome-text" text="Welcome" 
         GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

    <Label text="User Name:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <TextField 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Label text="Password:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
        <Button text="Sign In"     
        onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
    </HBox>

    <Text fx:id="actiontarget"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>

    <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@Login.css" />
    </stylesheets>

</GridPane>
```

Comment: javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)

Comment: I've added the example code I used to test my suggestion before I posted it. It runs for me fine in JDK 1.8.0_20. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: The constructLoadException means there's probably an error in your FXML or its Controller class.

Comment: Thanks alot the problem was, that the Controller classes wasnt loaded.Thats why it didnt work. But Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The call you make to [`Class.getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) looks on the classpath for the resource (unless you've done something funky with the class-loaders) and therefore will never find an *absolute* path.

If you want to load a file from an *absolute* path, just create an [`java.io.FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) using that path like this:

```
String fxmlpath = "C:\\plugin\\pluginfxml.fxml";
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(new FileInputStream(fxmlpath));
```

That said, I'd be careful with absolute paths, they're not very portable - it's more common to create a standard directory structure for your application and then add the necessary directories to the classpath.

For example your application might have a directory structure like this:

```
My Application
  + bin
  + conf
  + lib
  + plugins
```

Then assuming you run your application from the `bin` directory, you'd use a classpath like this:

```
../conf;../plugins;../lib/*
```

Which would allow you to do the following in your application:

```
String fxmlpath = "pluginfxml.fxml";
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Class.getResourceAsStream(fxmlpath));
```

Comment: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Class.getResourceAsStream(fxmlpath));

 what is Class ?

Comment: 'Class.getResourceAsStream' is a static method, see the JavaDoc for a description of which classloader is used - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Comment: But Class need a Type like Class<Object> or something

Comment: No, the genetic parameter is irrelevant in a static context.  The code will simply create an `InputStream` from a resource on the classpath (providing that resource exists)