# Unknown Path FXML document

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

We're writing an Java application using JavaFX. At this time we have 3 different forms:

- Login
- Game window
- Registration

For our next iteration, we want to implement the Registration form, but we get the IOException error `Unknown Path`

It's about this piece of code:

```
FXMLLoader registrationLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                    try{
                        mainroot = (Parent)registrationLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("FXMLRegistration.fxml").openStream());                            
                        Stage registrationStage = new Stage();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(mainroot);
                        registrationStage.setScene(scene);
                        registrationStage.setTitle("Register your account");
                        registrationStage.show();
                    } catch(IOException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
                    }
```

The above code is working when I change `FXMLRegistration.fxml` to `FXMLDocument.fxml` or `FXMLLoader.fxml`.

When I change

```
mainroot = (Parent)registrationLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("FXMLRegistration.fxml").openStream());
```

to

```
mainroot = (Parent)registrationLoader.load(Paths.get("src/hackattackfx/FXMLRegistration.fxml").toUri().toURL());
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605499/java-fxml-load-dynamic-from-absolute-path)

I get the absolute path in the debugger output, which is correct when I use it with the `file` command in terminal.

I hope someone could help us with this error.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I Changed some code to the following:

```
FXMLLoader registrationLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXMLRegistration.fxml"));
mainroot = (Parent)registrationLoader.load();
```

but this will return an IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
When I remove `/` before `/FXMLRegistration.fxml`, I get to my catch block printing the full path of the file:

> file:/Users/juleskreutzer/Documents/github/PTS3/HackAttackFX/dist/run1793658053/HackAttackFX.jar!/hackattackfx/FXMLRegistration.fxml

Also changing the path to `src/hackattackfx/FXMLRegistration.fxml` will give the IllegalStateException: Location not set.

**Project Structure**

We use different packages in our application. all these packages are within the default package: `hackattackfx`

The packages in the default package are:

- Default Package

  - Exceptions
  - Interfaces
  - enums
  - Resources
  - Templates
- JSON Package

My FXML documents are located in the default package (hackattackfx). If it's not 100% clear how I arranged my files, please take a look at [my Github repo](https://github.com/juleskreutzer/PTS3/tree/master/HackAttackFX/src/hackattackfx)

Comment: Your question is not very clear (to me). When you are using `Paths.get("src/hackattackfx/FXMLRegistration.fxml").toUri().toURL()` does it work? Is you aim to use `Paths.get()` ? If yes, why?

Comment: Paths.get() does not work, it prints the path to my debugger so it shouls get in my catch block. If possible, I want to use getClass().getResource("X").openStream()

Comment: You should use `getClass().getResource()` if you file is present on the classpath. Paths.get() doesn't make any sense under such circumstances.

Comment: When I use getClass().getResource(), the path also gets printed, but than it is ../HackAttack.jar!/hackattackfx/FXMLRegistration.fxml. I can't find this path in terminal, I think because the !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So, I got all curious to find out the root cause, I cloned the repo and found that the actual issue was the following error and the one that was posted by the OP in the question*

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at hackattackfx.FXMLRegistrationController.initialize(FXMLRegistrationController.java:67)

Which means that in the controller `pane` was null.

This was because the fxml was missing a declaration of `fx:id` .

Add `fx:id="pane"` to the AnchorPane declaration of `FXMLRegistration.fxml` and things should just work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try it when i'm back at my desk and will let you know if it worked!

Comment: Sorry, but your answers doesn't work for me. I edited my question with the results after trying your answer.

Comment: Can you add the project structure to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Path with  `/`

this is working for me:

```
final String fxmlPath = "/fxml/Main.fxml";
final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
```

`Main.fxml` is located in the resource folder (for me: `/src/main/resources/fxml/`)